# What is the best way to create inventory models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new on django. I'm making the simple inventory application. Here's my Model:

```
class Received(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    ....

class Sold(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    ....

class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOne(Item)
    weight_received = ?
    weight_sold = ?
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    ....

class InventoryHistory(models.Model):
    # I have no idea
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    total_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

What I wanna do is when:

1.) I do an input data on `Received` or `Sold` the `Inventory` should **automatically update** (where `Inventory.weight_in` is SUM of `Received.weight` and `Inventory.weight_out` is SUM of `Sold.weight`.)

2.) I do a delete on them, `Inventory` should be **automatically update**

3.) I do en edit on them, `Inventory` should be **automatically update**

Is it possible, and how?

And here's another one question about my lack of database knowledge problem. Is it necessary to me to make a `InventoryHistory` where I can track a history of inventory in daily?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/). In particular `django.db.models.signals.post_save` and `django.db.models.signals.post_delete`. For tracking history I recommend to use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion).

Comment: Thank you sir, it's work nicely. But how about `post_edit`? And, for now I still use an increment to `Inventory.weight_in` and `Inventory.weight_out` when the data have inputted. I want to ask you, is it good? Or I have to do a recounting (with for loop) and replace the value of `Inventory.weight_in` and `Inventory.weight_out`? -Thank you, sir.

Comment: `post_save` has parameter `created`, if its value is `True` then a new record was created else a record was edited.

Comment: Better use aggregation to calculate `weight_received` value: `weight_received = Received.objects.aggregate(Sum('weight'))`

Comment: Ok. So, if I use this aggregation I don't need to use `created` or `not created` option right?

Comment: No, you don't have to use loop to do a recounting. Use signal pre_save, in signal handler use `created` to determine is it creating or editing and use aggregation to get current `weight` value of all Received\Sold models.

Comment: for sure, I had to use `pre_save` or `post_save`? And, how to use 2 `sender`? In this case I will do `signal` when input/edit on `Received/Sold`.

Comment: My fault, of course `post_save`. Define two `post_save` handlers - one for `Received` and one for `Sold`.

Comment: Of course, too much question was my bad. Thank you so much btw.